# How can i auto adjust the height of my div based on image Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27yj94v8/4/) to my problem.

Basically i have a display on my website that show some images with text below it. The issue i have is the text under the images is too far from the images itself and not aligned.

The images are not of static height. The width is always 80 px, but the height varies from 80px to 150px and

As you can see the images appear disaligned. All i want to do is have the text below the images in a single line under the image with the most height.

HTML

```
<ul class="list-items list-carousel no-js">
    <li class="ccarousel-item">
        <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/sports" />                
        </div>
        <div>SPORTS</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ccarousel-item">
        <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/140/fashion" />                
        </div>
        <div>FASHION</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ccarousel-item">
        <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/120/animals" />                
        </div>
        <div>ANIMALS</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
}
.ccarousel-item {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pImgContainer {
height: auto;
width: 120px;
line-height: 110px;
padding-top: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

EDIT: I have changed my HTML a bit. i made a mistake while reproducing my code in the Fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/27yj94v8/1/

```
ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0 0 10px 25px;}
.ccarousel-item{float:left;overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;zoom:1;margin:0;padding:0;}
.pImgContainer{height:auto;width:120px;padding-top:10px;margin:0 auto;}
img+div{margin:0;padding:0;display:block;}
```

Comment: I want the text to be on the same line

Comment: So all text parallel?  Then just set a height to the container of the image, and put the text outside of that.

Comment: I dont want ot set a constant height. Because sometimes all the images height can be only 90px and if set height to 150px there is a lot of gap between these images and text.

Comment: Perfecto. All i wanted

Comment: oh.. ok.  Cool.  I was still fiddling with it because I thought that wasn't correct.  If all else fails I was going to say I guess you could set the height of the containers with jQuery based on the height of the tallest image in the group.

Answer (score 2):

For a start

```
.pImgContainer div{
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/27yj94v8/2/)

For an even better experience, set

```
.ccarousel-item {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pImgContainer {
  height:150px;
  width: 120px;
  line-height:110px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pImgContainer + div{
  bottom:-15px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/27yj94v8/10/)

Comment: You solution is very good. but i changed my HTML slightly. Please check edit

Answer (score 1):

Move the caption div out of `div.pImgContainer`.

```
<li class="ccarousel-item">
    <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/sports" />

    </div>
    <div>SPORTS</div>
</li>
```

And add the image container's min height (or just height) in your css:

```
.pImgContainer{
   min-height:150px;//the maximum height a picture could be
}
```

Comment: Then you can use min-height to align the texts (I don't know why jsfiddle doesn't work properly when I add min-height to your fiddle...) If you want to place the text as close as possible to the highest image (and the height is not fixed), you may consider to reorganize the elements - one div to list images, another to list texts, and each image container has same width with each text container.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem is in css:**

```
.pImgContainer {
   height: auto;
   width: 120px;
   line-height: 110px; //Remove the line-height.
   padding-top: 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this.. remove the line-height from .pImgContainer

Answer (score 1):

Just simply give the .pImgContainer a height of 150px since you know that's the highest value you will ever have.

http://jsfiddle.net/27yj94v8/9/

```
.pImgContainer {
   height:auto;
   width: 120px;
   line-height:110px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height:150px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mod

http://jsfiddle.net/t0o5gy5v/

```
<ul class="list-items list-carousel no-js">
<li class="ccarousel-item">
    <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
        <div class="image-box"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/sports" /></div>
        <div>SPORTS<div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="ccarousel-item">
    <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
        <div class="image-box"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/140/fashion" /></div>
        <div>FASHION</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="ccarousel-item">
    <div class="pImgContainer fk-text-center">
        <div class="image-box"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/120/animals" /></div>
        <div>ANIMALS</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0 0 10px 25px; } .ccarousel-item { float: left; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0; } .pImgContainer { height: auto; width: 120px; line-height: 110px; padding-top: 10px; margin: 0 auto; } .pImgContainer div { line-height:20px; }

.pImgContainer .image-box { height:150px; }